# Getting Record entries

Tags: c++, object-oriented

I have a class Record which keeps entries of strings(implemented using vector of strings). I want to keep the data member private to the class. To get entries, I have defined a member function get_entry which accepts a reference to vector of strings to store results.

Below is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Record {
public:
        void add_entry(const std::string& entry)
        {
                static int seq = 1;
                entries.push_back(std::to_string(seq++) + " "+ entry);
        }
        void get_entry(std::vector<std::string>& res) const
        {
                for (auto &v: entries)
                        res.push_back(v);
        }

private:
        std::vector<std::string> entries;
};

int main()
{
        Record name;
        name.add_entry("abc");
        name.add_entry("def");
        std::vector<std::string> res;
        name.get_entry(res);
        for (auto &v : res)
                std::cout << v << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Are there other better ways to get entries from such a class? I don't want to make `entries` data member public and access it directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious downside of your current approach is that you do a lot potentially unnecessary copying. One common solution is to return (const) iterators to the entries, i.e.,:

```
class Record
{
    public:
        // ...

       auto cbegin() const { return entries.cbegin(); }
       auto cend() const { return entries.cend(); }

       // Perhaps similar methods for getting non-const iterators ...
};
```

This solution allows you to use e.g., standard algorithms on the entries, but you can't manipulate the underlying range from the outside (due to const-ness).

To support your earlier use case, you can still do `std::vector<std::string> res(r.cbegin(), r.cend());` if you wish, where `r` is an object of type `Record`.

Answer (score 1):

Just return `entries` by value. It will make a deep copy automatically:

```
std::vector<std::string> get_entries() const
{
        return entries;
}
```